# I am trying to create a table with certain constraint, but I am getting invalid Identifier

Tags: sql, oracle10g

This is my code.

```
CREATE TABLE emp1(
  empno    NUMBER(4,0),
  ename    VARCHAR2(10),
  add      VARCHAR2(20), 
  job      VARCHAR2(9),
  mobile   NUMBER(10,0) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  mgr      NUMBER(4,0),
  hiredate DATE,
  sal      NUMBER(7,2),
  comm     NUMBER(7,2),
  dno   NUMBER(2,0),
  CONSTRAINT chk_name CHECK (name = lower(name)),
  CONSTRAINT chk_add CHECK (add='Kolkata' or add='Mumbai' or add='Delhi' or add='Mumbai'),
  CONSTRAINT chk_job CHECK (job='Clerk' or job='Manager' or job='Sales' or job='Analyst' or job='Manager'),
  CONSTRAINT chk_sal CHECK (sal>=0),
  CONSTRAINT pk_emp1 PRIMARY KEY (empno),
  CONSTRAINT fk_dno1 FOREIGN KEY (dno) REFERENCES dept1 (dno)
);
```

Name has to be lowercase.
Add can only be a certain values.
Sal must be positive.
Job can only be a certain values.

Comment: you don't have a "name" column in your list of columns. Did you mean "ename" instead in your chk_name constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a mistake with add keyword, which I was trying to use as address.

```
CREATE TABLE emp1(
  empno    NUMBER(4,0),
  ename    VARCHAR2(10),
  address  VARCHAR2(20), 
  job      VARCHAR2(9),
  mobile   NUMBER(10,0) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  mgr      NUMBER(4,0),
  hiredate DATE,
  sal      NUMBER(7,2),
  comm     NUMBER(7,2),
  dno   NUMBER(2,0),
  CONSTRAINT chk_ename CHECK (ename = lower(ename)),
  CONSTRAINT chk_add CHECK (address='Kolkata' or address='Mumbai' or address='Delhi' or address='Mumbai'),
  CONSTRAINT chk_job CHECK (job='Clerk' or job='Manager' or job='Sales' or job='Analyst' or job='Manager'),
  CONSTRAINT chk_sal CHECK (sal>=0),
  CONSTRAINT pk_emp1 PRIMARY KEY(empno),
  CONSTRAINT fk_dno1 FOREIGN KEY(dno,address) REFERENCES dept1(dno,location)
);
``
```